# Get hadoop streaming jobid

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

All Hadoop jobs have unique jobid. You can use jobid to get job status or job counters.
The question is how can I get jobid of the job I've just run from my script? And of course I want to do this in reliable and easy (if possible) way.

Example:

1) from my script I run:

```
hadoop jar      ${HADOOP_STREAMING} \
                -D mapred.job.name="$NAME" \
                -D mapred.reduce.tasks=$NREDUCERS\
                -mapper     "cat" \
                -file       ./reducer.py \
                -reducer    "python ./reducer.py" \
                -input       hdfs:/logs/2012-06-25/*.bz2 \
                -output      hdfs:/tmp/test
```

2) Now I want to somehow get *jobid* of the launched task.

3) When I have jobid, I can do hadoop job -status and hadoop job -counter queries.

**UPDATE:**

Synchronous case (wait until completion, get jobid and then ask for status/counters) seems to be the required minimum, but sometimes it's not convenient to use. Sometimes I want to run a few hadoop streaming jobs simultaneously (as background tasks) and I want to remember all jobids which I can use later, e.g. for workflow analysis.

In fact I've figured out some solution, but I consider it as a hack, which bothers me a lot. I would be grateful if somebody shows me more elegant solution. Here's the solution:

1) when I run a hadoop streaming job I must specify an *output hdfs directory*.

2) using this directory I can access job configuration file in hdfs:

```
CONF_FILE_PATH=`hadoop fs -stat hdfs:<output_dir_path>/_logs/history/*.xml | awk '{print $NF}'`
```

3) Finally, I can extract the jobid from the configuration file's name

Comment: In your example case, doesn't the execution wait until the job completes before the shell continues? (in which case there isn't much point polling the status). Or are you interested in finding out whether the job succeeded/failed and any final job counter values?

Comment: Synchronous case (wait until completion, get jobid and then ask for status/counters) seems to be the required minimum, but sometimes it's not convenient to use. Sometimes I want to run a few hadoop streaming jobs simultaneously (as background tasks) and I want to remember all jobids which I can use later, e.g. for workflow analysis.

In fact I've figured out some solution, but I consider it as a hack, which bothers me a lot (see an updated post). I would be grateful if somebody shows me more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options outside your current 'hack' (one of which is just another 'hack'!)

1. Capture the standard error of the running process, the job ID will be output in the first (few) lines, and has the format similar to: `Running job: <jobid>`.
2. Modify the [StreamJob.java](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/tags/release-1.0.3/src/contrib/streaming/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/streaming/StreamJob.java?view=markup) source code (around line 917) in the streaming contrib folder to output the job id to a tmp file (maybe pre / suffixed with the process ID for quick discovery from the shell).

Comment: I think the first approach is very unreliable, because stderr output may change in newer versions for example. At the moment I cannot try the second approach, but it seems to be OK and I'll try it later. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You have an option to assign user defined name to the job:

```
|-D mapred.job.name="unique_name_within_the_user" \
```

and after that identify your job_id from Hadoop YARN REST API's response:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET "http://host.domain.com:8088/ws/v1/cluster/apps"
```